# Xquery - what is wrong here

Tags: xquery, sequence, marklogic

I would like the node replace to act on the $person variable. What do I need to change?

The following code should change the name of the people in the sequence to X.

```
declare function local:ChangeName($person)
{
  xdmp:node-replace($person//Name/text, text { "X" } )

  <p>{$person}</p>
};

let $b := <Person>
      <Name>B</Name>
      <IsAnnoying>No</IsAnnoying>
  </Person>

let $j := <Person>
      <Name>J</Name>
      <IsAnnoying>No</IsAnnoying>
  </Person>

let $people := ($b, $j)

return $people ! local:ChangeName(.)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xdmp:node-replace()` only operates on persisted documents, not on in-memory documents.

Your `local:ChangeName()` function could construct the Person and Name elements but copying the **IsAnnoying** element, as in:

```
declare function local:ChangeName($person)
{
  <p>
  <Person>
  <Name>X</Name>
  {$person//IsAnnoying}
  </Person>
  </p>
};
```

For more complex transformations, consider a recursive typeswitch or **XSLT** transform.

Answer (score 1):

As Erik noted above, you can't apply the `xdmp` update functions to in-memory nodes.  If you have a strong need to to do in-memory node updates, Ryan Grimm's [memupdate](https://github.com/marklogic/commons/tree/master/memupdate) library can come in handy.  It basically does the grunt work of the recursive traversal for you.  But beware, in-memory updates do not scale to large documents because it requires making a copy to do an update.

https://github.com/marklogic/commons/tree/master/memupdate

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ML instance running, so I couldn't test it (maybe there are more issues), but it has to be

```
$person//Name/text()
```

instead of

```
$person//Name/text
```

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath:

```
$person//Name/text
```

should be:

```
$person//Name/text()
```

The XPath is looking to replace the text node, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the results of xdmp:node-replace will not be visible in the same transaction.  To see the results you need to start a new transaction.

Comment: Please can you help me with the syntax for this?